# Free alternative to EViews for ARIMA modelling

Tags: econometrics, software

Can someone guide me in acquiring an application similar to EViews? I need a free application where I can incorporate the ARIMA model.

Answer (score 5):

The standard open source statistical language is *R*. The R-Project homepage is [here](https://www.r-project.org/). Here is a page about [ARIMA in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/arima.html). If you want to try using R without having to install anything, then I would recommend [DataJoy](https://www.getdatajoy.com/), which provides a free web-based R environment.

Note that R is an entire statistical computing language, so you may find that there is quite a big overhead for learning the language before you can start doing your ARIMA analysis.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested above, R is an excellent language/program and suitable for almost anything in economics.

However, if you're looking for a free graphical interface program like Eviews, I'd give gretl (http://gretl.sourceforge.net/) a try.